# MQTT not receiving messages

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I can't receive messages from MQTT. The client is based on the mosquitto.dll. There are no onConnect and onMessage callbacks. However, the onDisconnect and onLog callbacks work normally. I can publish messages to the server.

```
server log:
1696166724: New connection from 127.0.0.1:59203 on port 1883.
1696166724: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:59203 as mqttx_22be153f (p5, c1, k60, u'user').
1696166724: No will message specified.
1696166724: Sending CONNACK to mqttx_22be153f (0, 0)
1696166724: Received SUBSCRIBE from mqttx_22be153f
1696166724:     testtopic/# (QoS 0)
1696166724: mqttx_22be153f 0 testtopic/#
1696166724: Sending SUBACK to mqttx_22be153f
1696166727: New connection from ::1:59204 on port 1883.
1696166727: New client connected from ::1:59204 as mqttx_d84dc2b6 (p2, c1, k100, u'user').
1696166727: No will message specified.
1696166727: Sending CONNACK to mqttx_d84dc2b6 (0, 0)
1696166727: Received SUBSCRIBE from mqttx_d84dc2b6
1696166727:     # (QoS 0)
1696166727: mqttx_d84dc2b6 0 #
1696166727: Sending SUBACK to mqttx_d84dc2b6
1696166730: Received PUBLISH from mqttx_d84dc2b6 (d0, q0, r1, m0, 'testtopic', ... (6 bytes))
1696166730: Sending PUBLISH to mqttx_22be153f (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'testtopic', ... (6 bytes))
1696166730: Sending PUBLISH to mqttx_d84dc2b6 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'testtopic', ... (6 bytes))
1696166733: Received PUBLISH from mqttx_22be153f (d0, q1, r0, m24914, 'testtopic', ... (21 bytes))
1696166733: Sending PUBLISH to mqttx_22be153f (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'testtopic', ... (21 bytes))
1696166733: Sending PUBLISH to mqttx_d84dc2b6 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'testtopic', ... (21 bytes))
1696166733: Sending PUBACK to mqttx_22be153f (m24914, rc0)
1696166737: Client mqttx_d84dc2b6 closed its connection.
1696166740: Received DISCONNECT from mqttx_22be153f
1696166740: Client mqttx_22be153f disconnected.
1696166747: mosquitto version 2.0.14 terminating
```

New connection from ::**1**:59204 on port 1883. It is strange

second is mttq client program, it work good

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

 extern "C" {
    #include <mosquitto.h>
}

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TForm1:: onConnect(struct mosquitto* mosq, void* userdata, int result) {
    if (result == 0)
    {
        CheckBox1->Checked=1;
    }
    else
    {
        CheckBox1->Checked=0;
    }

    Edit1->Text=IntToStr(result) + " int ";
}

void TForm1::onMessage(struct mosquitto* mosq, void* userdata, const struct mosquitto_message* message) {

Memo1->Lines->Add("massage");

}



__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{


}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
mosquitto_username_pw_set(mosq,"user", "*****");
int rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq, "localhost", 1883, 100);

if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
    Memo1->Lines->Add("mqtt not work" +IntToStr(rc) +"   ") ;
    }


rc= mosquitto_validate_utf8("#",1);
        if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
        Memo1->Lines->Add("mqtt val not ok ") ; }
        else
        {Memo1->Lines->Add("mqtt val ok ") ;}

mosquitto_subscribe(mosq, NULL, "#", 0);
    if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
        Memo1->Lines->Add("mqtt sub not work ") ;

    }

mosquitto_loop_start(mosq);


}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 void onConnect_(struct mosquitto* mosq, void* userdata, int result)
{
 Form1->onConnect(mosq,userdata, result);
}

  void onMessage_(struct mosquitto* mosq, void* userdata, const struct mosquitto_message* message)
{
 Form1->onMessage(mosq,userdata,message);
}

void onDisconnect_(struct mosquitto* mosq, void* userdata, int result)
{
 Form1->onConnect(mosq,userdata, result);
}

void onLog_(struct mosquitto* mosq, void* level, int cnt, const char *data)
{
 String ans = data;
 Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(ans);

}

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
     mosquitto_lib_init();

    mosq = mosquitto_new("mqttx_d84dc2b6", true, NULL);



    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosq, onConnect_ );
    mosquitto_disconnect_callback_set(mosq,onDisconnect_);
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosq, onMessage_ );
    mosquitto_log_callback_set(mosq,onLog_);




}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
    mosquitto_disconnect(mosq); // Отключение от брокера
    mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 mosquitto_disconnect(mosq);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
static int m;
mosquitto_publish(mosq ,NULL, "testtopic",6,"test1  123; ", 0, true );
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried  to change parameter for mosquitto_subscribe(mosq, NULL, "#", 0), different topic, QoS. I get Log from it :
CONNECT
Client mqttx_d84dc2b6 sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: #, QoS: 0, Options: 0x00)
Client mqttx_d84dc2b6 sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r1, m3, 'testtopic', ... (6 bytes))

Comment: Looks like your client successfully subscribes, as the broker is pushing the messages towards the client (`Sending PUBLISH to mqttx_d84dc2b6`...). So your problem is more likely in handling the messages correctly.

Comment: And the message `New connection from ::1:59204 on port 1883` is not strange at all. You are connecting to localhost (thus from ::1 which is the IPv6 Address of localhost) from port 59204 (randomly chosen) to port 1883.

Comment: problem is: libmosquitto on Windows is currently compiled without thread support, so
neither of mosquitto_loop_start() nor "mosquitto_pub -l" are available.